Flutter app integrated for Huawei but shows blank on EMUI HMS Devices
Hi so to be able to release my flutter app on both Google Play and Huawei AppGallery I had to integrate the HMS core services to my app and I've done so very carefully,I have managed to test my app in Android studio by installing the HMS core and AppGallery apps and then disabling the Google play services,this has worked and i was able to receive Huawei notifications on my app as well as make sure my app is not relying on google services in the Huawei build
After uploading the new version of my app to deploy to the store, My app is infinitely processing and then times out as below:

Also uploading to Cloud Debugging to test has been hard,My App shows blank when opened on a EMUI device(Functions perfectly on Android emulator) as below:

Ive went through the logs from the Cloud debugger but I'm unable to get a proper log concerning the issue as the logging is only system level
I have no idea why this is happening as I've double checked t hat everything should be working perfectly and all the Documentation was followed correctly
Note: This is only happening after separating the Google-services and Huawei services entirely for the builds using flavours and also in the app only the correct services get initialized based on the device
I please request any help on this if someone had a similar issue
Tested in cloud debugger, Double checked all the code and build files,Im unable to get a replication of this issue locally with proper app logs,Sentry is also not reporting a issue even thou the cloud debug version was a real version of the app
i expected the app to render,weirdly it did work in Cloud Debugger yesterday on the Huawei device but will not now

seems to be only the HMS build of the app having the issue with processing,the google versions do upload, this started to happen after I removed google-services.json from the flavour and made the build HMS only
